# Using Newtonsoft JsonConvert to serialize and deserialize simple class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to simply serialize and deserialize a simple class with JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj) and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string).

I'm using this in a custom TypeConverter for a QueryParameter in .NET Web API Core 2.1.

But I'm getting very strange behavior. My class looks like this:

```
public class ListRequestDto {
    public bool? WithCreator { get; set; }
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
    public int? Limit { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to do the following:

```
var test = new ListRequestDto {
    WithCreator = true,
    Skip = 0,
    Limit = 15
};
string ttt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

But I'm getting the following output:

```
"MyNameSpace.ListRequestDto"
```

If I try it the other way around:

```
string json = "{ WithCreator: true, Skip: 0, Limit: 15 }";
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListRequestDto>(json);
```

I get the following exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'MyNameSpace.ListRequestDto' because the type requires a JSON string value to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON string value or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'Skip', line 1, position 8."

I tried to remove the nullable fields (replacing them with regular primitives) but that resulted int he exact same error.

The strange thing is, that if I provide the same class as a body it works. And as far as I know Web API Core also uses the Newtonsoft Json Parser.

Comment: I tried your code for serialization and it works perfectly. Where do you see "MyNameSpace.ListRequestDto"? are you sure that's what you get in `ttt`?

Comment: And for deserialization you've forgot the quotes: `{"WithCreator":true,"Skip":0,"Limit":15}`

Comment: Actually, i tried with no quotes and works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it is necessary, but when I put [JsonObject] on my class it suddenly works.
The exception actually told me to do that, but I do not understand why it is necessary when in no documentation this is used in such a case.

So bascially doing the following solved the problem:

```
[JsonObject]
public class ListRequestDto {
    public bool? WithCreator { get; set; }
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
    public int? Limit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you have a custom TypeConverter applied to your class, Json.Net will try to use it for serialization and deserialization.  On serialization, this will result in a string value (whatever string the TypeConverter returns), and on deserialization it will expect the JSON to contain a string value because it wants to use the TypeConverter to turn it back into an object (hence the error you see).  Using the [JsonObject] attribute tells Json.Net that you want it serialized/deserialized as a regular object, and not to use the TypeConverter.